# Norm of an operator that is selfadjoint and positive

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I have a question about how to show these equalities,
$$|||T|||=|||T^{*}|||=||T||$$ and $$|||T||T^{*}|||=||T^{2}||$$ where $$|T|=(T^{*}T)^{\frac{1}{2}},|T^{*}|=(TT^{*})^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$
First guess is to use the definition $$\langle (T^{*}T)^{\frac{1}{2}}x,x\rangle = \langle x,(T^{*}T)^{\frac{1}{2}}x\rangle$$ But I dont seem to get how to connect it with $$(TT^{*})^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: Apply the property $\|A^*A\|=\|A\|^2$ for $A=T,$ $A=T^*,$ $A=|T|$ and $A=|T^*|.$ One equality namely $\|\,|T|\,|T^*|\,\|=\|T^2\|$ is false.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. I obtained the first equality with your help. Second equality is stated in a masters thesis on numerical radius and operator theory. Weird, maybe a printing mistake there. Thank you so much for answering!